# Container que se adapte a toda la altura de la pantalla

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy realizando un Login con bootstrap y no puedo hacer que el Container se adapte a todo el height de la pantalla.

Esta es la estructura del *container*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row align-items-stretch">
     <div class="col-xl-9 image"></div>
       <div class="col-xl-3">
         <form action="#" class="needs-validation" id="formulario">
         </from>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ya intenté con *height* , *max-height* , *min-height* y ninguna me quita ese espacio

Comment: y que version de BS estas usando ???

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es usar la clase `vh-100`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport

Comment: Me parece que esa clase trae padding en sus estilos, sobreescribela y añade la regla de ```padding:0;```

Comment: @Charls no, el padding de la clase no afecta el alto, en todo caso, no necesitarías crear reglas, sólo usa p-0. La respuesta de Pablo Lozano es correcta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Charls la clase _vh-100_ fue la solución <3

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las siguientes 2 opciones css aplicado a la div container-fluid:

**Opcion 1:**
`height: 100vh;` // esto es trabajando con lo que se llama "viewport"

**Opción 2:**

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
```

Ambas deberían funcionar bien, incluso si usas la clase container-fluid de Bootstrap.